# How does Applied Entropy (Control) and Sealed Scroll interact?

Tags: argent-the-consortium, argent-mancers-university

We were playing [Argent: The Consortium](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/144797/argent-consortium) (with [Mancers of the University](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/152230/argent-mancers-university) Expansion) and one of the players ended up getting the Applied Entropy spell to third level.

He then proceeded to target a Sealed Scroll with the Control (third level) spell.
How does this interaction work?

Since he's already at his regular action, can he use the fast action on this treasure?
If he can, where does the Sealed scroll go? His discard or the original owner's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the player can not target the sealed scroll.

The rules (emphasis from the printed rules) for fast actions State :-

> You may **not** use a Fast Action **after** you take your regular
>   Action.  Also, you may **not** use a Fast Action in place of a Regular
>   Action.

The Control spell, level 3 of Applied Entropy, says :-

> **Action:** use an opponents Treasure Card, exhausting it after use.

Sealed Scroll says :-

> **Fast Action:** Research a Legendary Spell of your choice, then place this into your personal discard pile.

So as the player is in his action phase he can not then go back and do anything that counts as a Fast Action from his own cards or that of another players.  As Control is 'Action' and Sealed Scroll is 'Fast Action' this is completely prevented.